# How to use "this" in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

i want to use this package [standard-error](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard-error)

they provide this example:

```
 var Http = require("http")
var StandardError = require("standard-error")
 
function HttpError(code, msg) {
  StandardError.call(this, msg || Http.STATUS_CODES[code], {code: code})
}
 
HttpError.prototype = Object.create(StandardError.prototype, {
  constructor: {value: HttpError, configurable: true, writable: true}
})
```

i want to replicated using typescript, but in this part of code i got this:

```
import { Errors } from './errors.enum';
import StandardError from 'standard-error';
import Http from 'http';

function StkError(code: number, msg: any) {
  let name = 'StkError';
  switch (code) {
    case Errors.BADREQUEST:
      name = 'Bad Request';
      break;
    case Errors.UNAUTHORIZED:
      name = 'Unauthorized';
      break;
    case Errors.FORBIDDEN:
      name = 'Forbidden';
      break;
    case Errors.NOTFOUND:
      name = 'Not Found';
      break;
    default:
      name = 'StkError';
  }

  StandardError.call(
    this,
    JSON.stringify({ body: msg.body, params: msg.request.params, query: msg.request.query }) || Http.STATUS_CODES[code],
    {
      code,
    },
  );
}

StkError.prototype = Object.create(StandardError.prototype, {
  constructor: { value: StkError, configurable: true, writable: true },
});

const Mockctx = {
  body: {
    test: 'test',
  },
  request: {
    params: {
      param1: '1',
    },
  },
  otro: '',
};
```

'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

with "quick fix" of vscode i got this

```
 function StkError(this: { value: typeof StkError; configurable: boolean; writable: boolean; }, code: number, msg: any) {
  let name = 'StkError';
  switch (code) {
    case Errors.BADREQUEST:
      name = 'Bad Request';
      break;
    case Errors.UNAUTHORIZED:
      name = 'Unauthorized';
      break;
    case Errors.FORBIDDEN:
      name = 'Forbidden';
      break;
    case Errors.NOTFOUND:
      name = 'Not Found';
      break;
    default:
      name = 'StkError';
  }

  StandardError.call(
    this,
    JSON.stringify({ body: msg.body, params: msg.request.params, query: msg.request.query }) || Http.STATUS_CODES[code],
    {
      code,
    },
  );
}
```

but now it says: Expected 2 arguments, but got 3

i'm stucked, thank you for your help

Comment: It seems you're using `StandardError.call` not `StkError.call`?

Comment: Yes like in the example. 
Imported in this line var StandardError = require("standard-error")

Comment: `class StkError extends StandardError { … }` should do it.